# Login from external database ASP.NET Core 2.2

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication

I'm a rookie with just a few months of training in programming, so please don't be harsh on me.

Right now I'm working on a simple MVC web app using ASP.NET Core 2.2. My problem is that I have to implement login, with users, that are already provided in a external database.

I have read a number of articles and forums and I can't quite find what I'm looking for. Most of the articles are about extending the built-in authentication of ASP.NET Core which I can't use. The ones that implement fully custom login from external database are written based on older versions of ASP.NET Framework - so I have troubles understanding it, being a newbie at this.

I will be grateful for any kind of directions, suggestions, step by step tutorials etc.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must need you googled but first i found some post for this problem like this,

this post about CRUD operations with sql server 2017 - [Basic CRUD](https://developer.okta.com/blog/2019/04/24/crud-app-aspnet-core-sql-server)

possible you know this web site here for understand .net core or folder structure [.net Core Tutorial](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/core)

I absolutely recommend this man for every topic about .net core/ .net this post basic [Simple API for Authentication](https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2018/06/26/aspnet-core-21-simple-api-for-authentication-registration-and-user-management)

[Authentication and Authorization](https://medium.com/datadriveninvestor/authentication-vs-authorization-716fea914d55)
 last 2 post for basic login

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/asp-net-core-razor-pages-simple-login-using-entity-framework-database-first-app/

http://future-shock.net/blog/post/creating-a-simple-login-in-asp.net-core-2-using-authentication-and-authorization-not-identity